# Convert a jQuery .load to $.ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, coffeescript

I initially tried to do this using $.ajax, but was not successful.  .load treated me good, so I used it.  However, now I find myself needed some callBacks that come with $.ajax.

```
 jQuery ->
   fl = $("#flight_flightlesson_id")
     fl.on "change", ->
       $("#gradable_items_container").load("gradable_items_inputs?lesson=#{fl.val()} #ajax_gradable_items_for_lesson_content")
```

When the chosen lesson input changes this passes the lesson_id as a url param to the flights_controller action gradable_items_inputs, populates a template of the same name, and loads that content into the browser without a reload.  Works great.

However, I want to use these callbacks

```
  beforeSend: ->
    $("#ajax_tell").addClass "is-fetching"

    //success: (response) ->
    //  $("#gradable_items_container").html(response)

    complete: (response) ->
      $("#ajax_tell").removeClass "is-fetching"
      alert "complete"

    error: ->
      $("#{ajax_tell}").html "<p>ERROR</p>"
      alert "error"
```

How would I convert my existing .load to this $.ajax?

Comment: Look the pattern: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: You can use the callback from `.load`. Before you send it, set the class of `is-fetching`, then use the `callback` to handle the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.load()` is simply a convenience method wrapper of `$.ajax()` with some options alredy set up like  `dataType:'html'` as well as automatically populating selector with response using `html()` method on ajax success.

Same is true for `$.post(), $.get(), $.getJSON()` etc

Follow the `$.ajax()` api and use any of the options you need to do same thing with a bit more flexibility.

The only ultra critical options are `url` and success or done or complete callback where you use `html()` to match `load()` method. API outlines defaults for other options if any and there are plenty of examples all over the place

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a good conversion

```
  fl = $("#flight_flightlesson_id")
  fl.on "change", ->
    $.ajax
      url: "gradable_items_inputs?lesson=#{fl.val()}"

    beforeSend: ->
      $("#ajax_tell").addClass "is-fetching"

    complete: ->

    success: (data) ->
      // $("#gradable_items_container").empty().append $(data).find("#ajax_gradable_items_for_lesson_content")
      $("#gradable_items_container").html(data).find("#ajax_gradable_items_for_lesson_‌​content")
      $("#ajax_tell").removeClass "is-fetching"

    error: ->
      $("#{ajax_tell}").html "<p>ERROR</p>"
```

Comment: if use `html()` method will reduce `.empty().append()` to one method call and better dom efficiency